# Kendo grid expand row does not always fire on change event

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I have a kendo grid set up so that the onChange event for the grid (record selection) will populate some ko vars that are vital to actions that the user will perform later.

One particular example being when a user expands a row, we go to a service to get that record's detail data.

This is functional about 90% of the time, but the kendo grid is capable (every now and then!!!) of a detail row being expanded without that row being selected. You have to hit the drill-down button just right, but it is possible.

I need to either prevent that behavior, or hack it so that I can fire that onChange. In the detailInit, I did do some playing around with firing a select() on the row with no luck...

I could do some selection from within an expand() or a detailInit(), but I would rather just fire the onChange(). Up for anything...

an example:

```
getGrid: function (selector, dataSource) {
            return $(selector).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                change: this.offenderVictimGridChange,
                selectable: "single",
                sortable: true,
                resizable: true,
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true,
                },
                detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#offender-detail-template").html()),
                detailInit: this.victimOffenderDetailInit,
```

.......

```
    offenderVictimGridChange: function (args) {
                dataContext.selectedOffender(this.dataItem(this.select()));


 },
```

.......

It is within victimOffenderDetailInit() that I will need dataContext.selectedOffender(), and that is the entire problem.

dataContext.selectedOffender() is set on the change (which 90% of the time is fired on the opening of a record).

Comment: afaik, There are few people have activity in [tag:kendo-ui] , so provide a simple example of your issue to increase the chance of getting solution. (in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is better). Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I added some snippets. A jsFiddle wouldn't be sufficient, because of the rarity of this bug. Most people would just leave with the mentality that they were unable to duplicate.

Comment: I was able to go hacktacular and set dataContext.selectedOffender to e.data from within offenderVictimGridChange()....I am still looking for a legit fix to this, though